# With Safe Authkit, how to authenticate with crypto wallet (not social login/email)?

Tags: safe-core-sdk, safe-core

I see [here](https://docs.safe.global/safe-core-aa-sdk/auth-kit) in the documentation (at the time of writing), it says "The Auth Kit creates an Ethereum address and authenticates a blockchain account using an email address, social media account, **or crypto wallet like Metamask.**".

However, I have not been able to achieve authentication with an existing crypto wallet. In fact, when I look at the [reference docs](https://docs.safe.global/safe-core-aa-sdk/auth-kit/reference/safeauthpack#signin-safeauthsigninoptions) for `signIn()`, it only specifies options for social media and email. Is there an undocumented configuration? Or perhaps this was phased out?

Answer (score 0):

As of now, `safeAuth` only supports Google Auth. We are currently working with Web3Auth to extend it to all providers they support, including also Metamask.

Please refer to the docs and/or repo in the near future for further updates as we are rolling out this new version.

Thank you for your patience in the meantime

Hope it helps,
Louis